# Thousands separator using Period on Javascript Function (ASP.net)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, string-formatting, separator, onkeyup

Sorry if duplicated, but I really confused with these javascript.
Please help me, if willing.

I have this javascript function that already worked, this function will add thousands separator with commas :

```
function addCommas(x) {
  //remove commas
  retVal = x ? parseFloat(x.replace(/,/g, '')) : 0;

  //apply formatting
  return retVal.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "."); 
}
```

And I call this function in the textbox, like this :

```
 Number Format <asp:TextBox ID="txtPrice" runat="server" onkeyup="this.value=addCommas(this.value);"></asp:TextBox>
```

The output, looked like this (the separator using commas):

> 60,000,234

BUT I want the output, looked like this (the separator using period) :

> 60.000.234

Give me a solution still using these Javascript function, please. Thanks

Comment: try this : `function addCommas(x) {var retVal= x.toString().replace(/[^\d]/g, '').replace(/(.{3})/g,'$1.'); return retVal;}` ... it will ignore everything except numbers and dot(s) will be inserted on every 3th place. and, of course, like `onkeyup` add `onkeypress` too in Your `textbox`.

Comment: @nelek But when the character reaches string period (.) - the function ignore me from pressing backspace. And also the period not correct, example when I typing 8 character of number "60000234", it will become "600.002.34".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I notice what was wrong in my code in comment.

Try this, I used it long time ago.

```js
function addCommas(x) {
 var retVal=x.toString().replace(/[^\d]/g,'');
  while(/(\d+)(\d{3})/.test(retVal)) {
   retVal=retVal.replace(/(\d+)(\d{3})/,'$1'+'.'+'$2');
 }
 return retVal;
}
```

```html
Number <input type="text" onkeypress="this.value=addCommas(this.value);" onkeyup="this.value=addCommas(this.value);" />
```

I hope so this will help You.

Answer (score 0):

```
function addCommas(x) {
    x = '' + x;
    //remove commas
    retVal = x ? parseFloat(x.replace(/,/g, '')) : 0;
    //apply formatting
    return retVal.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "."); 
}
```

It's still your function, but the variable x is converted into a string first.